# When creating a list of clients, should Address be a struct (Class Client)?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a windows forms application using C# that will store clients/contacts. I'm not sure what the best way to add address would be, separate string values, a class, a struct... or?

I have no clue. What do you think?

Answer (score 3):

It's generally a good idea to decompose such an entity like a postal address into a separate data type. A few reasons: reusability, readability, separation of concerns.

Second, it's a generally good idea to avoid structs unless you 1) know what you are doing, 2) you really need them for their specific value-type semantics.

Hence, in your case create an `Address` class.

Answer (score 0):

Use a class. Structs are evil ;)

Comment: Hardly evil, but it's easy to make mistakes if you don't understand them well.

Comment: That's what makes them "evil" :D

Comment: Not any more than a poisonous snake is "evil". It's not evil, you just need to stay away from the sharp end.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I would create a separate class to represent an address.  A struct wouldn't serve in this case because there is too much data within an address to yield any benefit from it's use.